# Force equal height in grid / card content

Tags: flexbox, semantic-ui

I have a very simple test page

```
<div class="ui two column stretched grid padded" style="height: 100%;">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="ui card fluid">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="ui card fluid">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui card fluid">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Content</h1>
        <h1>Content</h1>
        <h1>Content</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(and body is also set to 100%, so that it fill the entire viewport)

Without any content in the third card, this is all equal height, and looks good. When I start adding content to it, it expands and takes space from the second card.

What I'm trying to do, is to force them to have equal height, even when there is content in only one of them.

Any suggestions? (I'm assuming its related to flexbox, but I haven't been able to pin down the issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `flex:1` to the cards which tells it to shrink and grow according to the available height. Added a custom class so that it is separate from Semantic UI's code.

OP's custom Chrome hack: Adding `flex-basis: 0` retains the original image height and width in Chrome.

```css
.eq-card.ui.card {
  flex: 1; /* Shrink and grow according to available height */
  flex-basis: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.4/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="ui two column stretched grid padded" style="height: 100%;">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="ui card fluid">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="ui card fluid eq-card">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui card fluid eq-card">
      <div class="content">
        <h1>Content</h1>
        <h1>Content</h1>
        <h1>Content</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution works great in Firefox.. but not in latest Chrome sadly.. Maybe I need to add `flex: 1` to more places..

Comment: There have been too many inconsistencies with flexbox in many browsers. Need to hack for some browsers until it is completely supported. Let me show if I can find a webkit solution.

Comment: Building on what you gave me, I added `flex-basis: 0` and now it works in Chrome, thanks for the help (feel free to update your answer, and I will accept it)

Comment: Good find. Thanks, that's nice of you for deleting your answer and suggesting it here :)

Comment: Yeah, I added it.. but wasn't sure what exactly is the etiquette here.. accepted your answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add the following css to the direct parent of the card element.

```
.card-container { 
display: flex; 
align-items: stretch; 
}
```

This will stretch all the flex items/ child components to fill the container.